# Understanding the XAML Silverlight Model: Adding lines to a canvas?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, data-binding

I have a canvas element and I'd like to draw grid lines on it ( so it ends up kind of looking like engineering paper),.

As I see it, there are a couple ways to do this:

1. Use XAML and copy/paste "Path" elements into the canvas and vary the top,left properties
2. Use Code to add grid lines
3. Databinding?

XAML is straight forward, but cumbersome.
Code is also straight forward.

I'm not sure about the last one. I keep thinking using code-behind to build controls is the Winforms way of doing things, and I'd prefer to do things the "proper way." So would I create a list of "top" and "left" values, and have lines generated from that? Or is databinding really used for putting data in excel grids and the like?

Comment: Are these dynamic lines or do you know ahead of time what you need to build...also with either code behind or the XAML it is about defining the data while data binding is about representing the data so they are not necessarily separate entities.

Comment: I know ahead of time. The lines are static aids to help place shapes on a canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use code.  It will give you the flexibility to modify and adjust this spacing of your grid and definitely follows DRY principles.

You could write something like the following pseudo-code:

```
int width = 500;
int height = 500;
int increment = 5;

int i = 0;
public void DrawHorizontalLines() {
   while (i <= height) {
      DrawHorizontalLine(i);
      i += increment;
}

public void DrawHorizontalLine(int startY) {
  //pseduo code to draw line goes here
  //line starts from X=0 and goes to X=width and begin Y spaces from the top
}
```

Add if you like, you can place all lines inside a rectangle so that you can easily show/hide the rectangle thereby show/hide the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are static, i.e. their locations do not change, I would add them in code-behind for speed and simplicity.

Databinding is good for binding data that is dynamic, i.e. changing. Also, defining the appearance of the data in XAML as a template allows you to 'skin' or 'theme' your UI. However, in your case I think a simple approach is probably the best.